# Daily running average in Google Sheets possible or not?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I work at a job wherein I receive tips. I have set up a sheet to keep track of the tips I make throughout the year. I have all the formulas set up that I want, save for one. I am trying to figure out a formula that will show a running daily average.

For example, if I make the following tips the first week,

```
34
100
21
30
24
```

then I would want it to show my daily average after each day. Does anyone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

If you have those tips down column A, rows 1-5, you could put the following in cell B1, or wherever you choose to have your running daily average field.

```
=SUM($A$1:A1)/ROWS($A$1:A1)
```

Then you will want to fill that formula (dragging the little + at the lower right corner of the B1 cell) down through the rest of your days.  When you fill the formula, the anchored cell will remain for every formula, but each new row/day will add a new value and count into the calculation.

The resulting formulas should be:

```
=SUM($A$1:A1)/ROWS($A$1:A1)
=SUM($A$1:A2)/ROWS($A$1:A2)
=SUM($A$1:A3)/ROWS($A$1:A3)
=SUM($A$1:A4)/ROWS($A$1:A4)
=SUM($A$1:A5)/ROWS($A$1:A5)
...
```

and the resulting values for your daily tips:

```
34
67
51.6666666666667
46.25
41.8
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in column A, you would enter in cell B1 the formula:

```
=average($a$1:a1)
```

Then fill that formula down column B getting something like:

```
=average($a$1:a1)
=average($a$1:a2)
=average($a$1:a3)
=average($a$1:a4)
=average($a$1:a5)
... etc.
```

getting the following result data:

```
34
67
51.66666667
46.25
41.8
... etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

- paste in **B2** and drag down:

  ```
  =AVERAGE(INDIRECT("A2:A"&ROW()))
  ```

  [image: 0]